# Comparing Ratios of Sexual Size Dimorphism

Tags: permutation-test, ratio

I am trying to find a test to compare degrees of sexual size dimorphism (SSD) between different populations. SSD is easily calculated as the ratio of the mean male size:mean female size.

I have four populations, and in each population, the numbers of males and females are different (e.g., pop 1: n(males)=35, n(females)=25; pop 2: n(males)=45, n(females)=28).

I do a lot of ANOVAs to compare differences in males and females between populations, but because each population only provides a single value/ratio for SSD, I am not sure how to compare these.

A permutation test was suggested by a colleague, but I'm not quite sure how to do this in R or any other package.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that permutation testing immediately confers an answer to this problem.

If you carefully read the problem, you'll see that an ordinary linear model suffices to test the hypothesis about whether the ratio of average sizes between males and females differs substantially between species.

I would do this analysis by fitting two models. First I would create a transformed logSize variable, so that you are comparing geometric means (e.g. differences in ratios). Then I would create a "full model" by regressing logSize on categorical effects for gender, species, as well as the two way interaction between gender and species. I would fit a "reduced model" which regresses logSize on categorical gender and species as before, *but omits the interaction*. A likelihood ratio test, or other appropriate structured test of nested linear models, would be correct in assessing the hypothesis.

This gives a test for whether the interaction effects are significant. Since I assume there's more than one species, this ANCOVA approach is suited to testing multiple simultaneous effects, or a difference in the grand-mean of interaction effects.

Basically, the interaction allows the male-female ratio to differ between species, whereas the reduced model fits the data under the assumption that average size differs between species but the male-female ratio is constant. Each interaction effect can be interpretted as a discrepancy in male-female ratios for that species compared to the principle species (which is arbitrary).

Very nice question.

Comment: It's actually different introduced populations of the same species. SSD is different qualitatively between the populations, and I want to see if, relative to the ancestral population, SSD has increased or decreased in the same direction in all introduced populations.

Does this affect your suggestions at all?

Comment: @M.0. as long as the different populations that you are trying to compare can be summarized using categorical effects, the basic approach remains exactly the same.

Comment: This is great! Thanks! Just want to make sure everything is clear:

So when I do the full model, all terms are significant (i.e., location (population), sex, and their interaction). So, I can interpret this as follows: the relationship of male:female size differs across locations, correct?

And in the reduced model, both sex and location are significant (but I deduced this from ANOVAs and t-tests earlier)?

Comment: @M.0. The significance of effects for sex and population is irrelevant. Whether they are significant or not has no bearing on results in either model, but it does describe the data in some mildly useful ways. It is the significance of their interaction which is important. Significance of the interaction says that the sex differences are not consistent between populations (i.e. there are sex differences between populations).

Comment: @M.0. only the joint test of nested models will give you the p-value to describe the statistical significance of the hypothesis test as I've stated.